# Optimized list filtering on implementation of Project Euler 23

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

I'm new to Haskell, the part of my code I'm concerned with is the `isSumAbundant` function. Surely there must be a better way, in an imperative language I might use a for loop and break out of the loop if i got greater than n, but it seems like having to filter the list for every single function call is not optimal.

The problem is Problem 23 from project-euler.net.

```
projectEuler23 =
  let a = abundantNums 28124 in
  sum [x | x <- [1..28124], not $ isSumAbundant x a]

isSumAbundant n a =
  any (\x -> (n - x) `elem` a) (takeWhile (<n) a)

abundantNums n =
  [x | x <- [1..n], (>x) $ sum $ properDivisors x]

properDivisors n =
  let  limit = (floor.sqrt.fromIntegral) n in
  [limit | limit^2 == n]
  ++ ((1:) $ concat [ [x, div n x] | x <- [2..limit - 1], rem n x == 0])
```

Comment: `elem` is linear, here's some cryptic pointlesser linear self-intersection. `isSumAbundant n = any (not . null . tail) . group . sort . ap (++) (map (n-)) . takeWhile (<n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add type signatures. Without type signatures, your integral types will default to `Integer`. So let us add type signatures:

```
projectEuler23 :: Int
projectEuler23 =
  let a = abundantNums 28124 in
  sum [x | x <- [1..28124], not $ isSumAbundant x a]

isSumAbundant :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
isSumAbundant n a =
  any (\x -> (n - x) `elem` a) (takeWhile (<n) a)

abundantNums :: Int -> [Int]
abundantNums n =
  [x | x <- [1..n], (>x) $ sum $ properDivisors x]

properDivisors :: Int -> [Int]
properDivisors n =
  let  limit = (floor.sqrt.fromIntegral) n in
  [limit | limit^2 == n]
  ++ ((1:) $ concat [ [x, div n x] | x <- [2..limit - 1], rem n x == 0])
```

Note that a type signature on `projectEuler23` would have been enough. Operations on `Int` are usually faster than `Integer`.

In `isSumAbundant` you can stop at `` n`div`2 ``, e.g.

```
isSumAbundant n a = any (\x -> (n - x) `elem` a) $ takeWhile (<= (n `div` 2)) a
```

Similar in `abundantNums`, you can use `scanl1`:

```
abundantNums n =
  [x | x <- [1..n], any (x <) $ scanr1 (+) $ properDivisors x]
```

This models your "break" from imperative languages.